# Linking to python 2.7 from C on Linux

Tags: python, c, linker, makefile, embedding

Hello I am having  problem linking my .so file t Python on Linux systems. (I got this working just fine on MacOS X and Windows but am stuck on this)

Currently the link flags are as follows:

```
LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic -L$(GTKLIBPREFIX) -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -rdynamic -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -ldl -lXi -lXext -lX11 -lm
```

And the compile flag is set to:

```
PYTHON =  /usr/local/include/python2.7 -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
```

Using the so file I build will result in unresolved symbols.

Then I thought doing ldd on the build so file since I would think I should see python here ??

What I got is this:

```
  linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7f3f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb7f3b000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libutil.so.1 (0xb7f36000)
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb7be6000)
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb7b62000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xb7b5e000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb7acc000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXi.so.6 (0xb7ac4000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXext.so.6 (0xb7ab7000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0xb79ed000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb79c7000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb78e8000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb78dd000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb77a9000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x80000000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0xb7793000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0xb778a000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0xb7750000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0xb7736000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb76fc000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/libcairo.so.2 (0xb769a000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xb766b000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1 (0xb7662000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXinerama.so.1 (0xb765f000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/libXrandr.so.2 (0xb765c000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXcursor.so.1 (0xb7653000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3 (0xb764e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb7644000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0xb7641000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xb763c000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0xb7611000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0xb75a7000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb7593000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0 (0xb756e000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0xb7550000)
```

With no hint of Python.

Linker flags were found by doing:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config$ python2.7-config --ldflags
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here ? (note Linux make files is really not strong side for me)

Comment: "Using the so file I build will result in unresolved symbols." -- you need to explain *how* you are using the `so` file and *which* symbols are unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding to the link flags:
  -Wl,-R/home/me/mylibdir
See also LD_RUN_PATH